# What is this form of code called in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to Javascript and I want to know what is the below pattern of code called.

```
GetDatasetProtocols: workbookId => `${API_QUERY_SVC_URL}dataset/protocols/${workbookId}`
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

That is an arrow function. The most important difference of an arrow function compared to a "regular" function is that the `this` keyword within an arrow function des not refer to the object the function is called from, but to the scope where the function is defined.

Arrow functions have been introduced in ES6. You can use them in *TypeScript* also when you target earlier JS versions. *TypeScript* will produce code that emulates the scope of `this` in the arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

Besides arrow functions, you also have `template literals` here: `${API_QUERY_SVC_URL}dataset/protocols/${workbookId}`

Check documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)